# wget not working properly inside a Perl program

Tags: perl, unix

I am trying to download some xml files from a given URL. Below is the code which I have used for the same-

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url ='https://givenurl.com/';
my $username ='scott';
my $password='tiger';

system("wget --user=$username --password=$password $url") == 0 or die "system execution failed ($?): $!";
local $/ = undef;
open(FILE, "<index.html") or die "not able to open $!";
my $index = <FILE>;
my @childs = map /<a\s+href\=\"(AAA.*\.xml)\">/g , $index;

for my $xml (@childs)
{
  system("wget --user=$username --password=$password $url/$xml");
}
```

But when I am running this, it gets stuck in the for-loop wget command. It seems wget is not able to fetch the files properly? Any clue or suggestion?

Thank you.

Man

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Have you tried replacing `system` with `print`? Does it get stuck on the first  `system`? What do the `system`s return?

Comment: It gets stuck after fetching several files.. sometimes it fetches two files sometimes at last file..

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use an external command in the first place.
Ensure that [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) is available, then use code like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

...

$mech->credentials($username, $password);
$mech->get($url);
foreach my $link ($mech->find_all_links(url_regex=>qr/\bAAA/)) {
    $mech->get($link);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$url` or `$xml` contains any shell metacharacters (`?` and `&` are common ones in URLs) then you may need to either quote them properly

```
system("wget --user=$username --password=$password '$url/$xml'");
system qq(wget --user=$username --password=$password "$url/$xml");
```

or use the `LIST` form of `system` that bypasses the shell

```
system( 'wget', "--user=$username", "--password=$password", "$url/$xml");
```

to get the command to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because the path to wget, what if you use:

```
system("/usr/bin/wget --user=$username --password=$password $url")
```

or I guess it can be a problem with variables passed to `system`: (`$username`, `$password`, `$url`)

Comment: It works for several files but not for other. Moreover it gets stuck randomly when I am executing the script multiple times.. :(

Comment: Try changing the `system` by `print` and see the output ... maybe the  `$url` is bad formated, if that is the case then you could use the `URL` module to build the `$url`... good luck