# wget from a command line

Tags: perl, wget

I can download a file from another server using wget command on a Linux command line, example:

```
wget ftp_site_name/file_name
```

But I could not download the same file when I run wget inside a perl script

```
system "/usr/bin/wget ftp_site_name/file_name";
```

or

```
system "wget ftp_site_name";
```

Here is the snippet of the error message:

```
Resolving ftp site  ...xx.xx.x.xx

Connecting to ftp site|xx.xx.x.xx|:xx... connected.

Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!

==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.

==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/??/??/ ...

No such directory `pub/??/??/'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are those `??` literally in the path you're using, or is that just some anonymization?

Comment: same here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298198/wget-not-working-properly-inside-a-perl-program][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298198/wget-not-working-properly-inside-a-perl-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what's wrong without the actual error message but I have some guesses:

If the path contains wild chars or spaces use apostrophe or escaping.

```
my $ftpname="/pub/some path with spaces/works_with_wildchar?/";
my $out = `wget '$ftpname'`;
print "out:\n$out\n";

or
my $ftpname="/pub/some path with spaces/works_with_wildchar?/";
my $out = qx!wget $ftpname!;
print "out:\n$out\n";
```

Comment: The exact error message is what I have explained in my first message
--2012-11-11 12:49:36--  ftp://server.name/pub/incoming/2009/1000/filename
           => `filename'
Resolving server.name... 20.44.0.16
Connecting to server.name|20.44.0.16|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/incoming/2009/1000 ...
No such directory `pub/incoming/2009/1000'.

Comment: Basically the directory "pub/incoming/2009/1000" does exist but it is unable to find it.

Comment: So using "my $out = qx!wget $ftpname!;" did not able to solve my issue. It has the same error message as before as indicated in my previous messages.